# Is it possible to deploy an entire web app to EOS?

Tags: web

Since some weeks ago a coworker and I have been studying how to set up the EOS local environment to create wallets, keys, accounts, smart contracts, and how to use the persistence API. That's alright now, we could eventually be able to develop the back-end of our application on EOS.

However, our aim is to develop a decentralized web application and we're investigating if it's possible to build a complete web application on top of EOS. To achieve that we'd need a kind of decentralized web server that serves files to the browser, for example. Additionally, we will have DNS name-ip mapping issues as this app will be running on a distributed system.

Summarizing, my questions are: Is it possible to have a web application completely hosted on EOS? What about the DNS names? Do you know any open source web page running on EOS at the moment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This may help: https://steemit.com/eos/@eosio/introducing-eos-io-application-stack

Ultimately, we are still waiting on IPFS to be integrated.  As of now, all storage needs to be done with RAM.  This is not feasible for the time being; however, as time progresses, BPs will increase the amount of RAM stored and once IPFS is released (probably Oct-Dec) then much more will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, EOS isn't for hosting files, it will take a few pieces to create a decentralised web app.

Web apps are usually composed of the front end and the back end,

Front end typically consists of HTML, CSS and JavaScript, all of this doesn't need to be on the Blockchain as storing the "About Us" page and your logo would be of no utility to the Blockchain.

You can instead distribute the front end with IPFS which does P2P file delivery, aka decentralised. It's a lot like Torrents.

The web app distributed through IPFS can then engage the Blockchain via Scatter and use your Smart contract as the backend.

In the future, you can also have nodes seed your IPFS data using EOS Storage but that is yet to come, at the moment other computers can seed the IPFS hash instead. Learn more at http://ipfs.io where you can also seek existing decentralised websites.

Answer (score -2):

Put it simply. It's impossible due to ability of BPs.

However there are some alternative approaches I suggest you should take a look at Skycoin.